# Dash does not find any photo

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash

I have a problem with the dash browser. I cannot find any photo (I have to go to its respective folder).

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu system from 12.04 to 14.04. I do not know what is happening with the dash browser that it does not find any photo. I do not know whether I need to install a/some package/s or it is just a issue of the name of folders.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved the problem.

To locate the photos on the dash, those need to be imported into "Shotwell Photo Manager"